# They are a or It is a

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

The question is: What days are the first and the second of July?
What is correct: 
- It is a Monday and a Tuesday.
or
- They are a Monday and a Tuesday.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Because your question is asking about the day**s** July 1 and 2, the answer should correspondingly answer regarding the day**s**.

Thus,

> They are a Monday and a Tuesday

is correct.

Comment: We frequently think about two things together as a single pair. For example, we say: **The couple is expected to arrive.....** So it would be quite acceptable to say:**It's a Monday and a Tuesday that are proving awkward in your proposed rota.** Here you are considering the two days as a single problem. Equally, you can say:**It's a cat and a dog that I can see in the yard.**